# Java code print powers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I wanted to know if I can turn this code into a while loop & do-while loop. Is this possible, and how?

```
       public class printPowers {





       public static void main(String[] args) {
       final int NMAX=4;  
      final double XMAX=5;

    System.out.println();

    for (double x =1; x <= XMAX; x++){
    for(int n =1; n <= NMAX; n++){
    System.out.printf("%10.0f",Math.pow(x,n));
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: please follow naming convention by naming your printPowers to PrintPowers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     final int NMAX=4;  
      final double XMAX=5;

    System.out.println();

    double x = 1;
    while(x<=XMAX){
      int n = 1;
      while(n<=NMAX){

        System.out.printf("%10.0f",Math.pow(x,n));
        n++;
      }
      System.out.println();
      x++;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Hello, I made it like this but it wont print the table. what should I do?                                                                                                     public static void  printTable() {
          final int NMAX=4;  
      final double XMAX=5;

    System.out.println();

    double x = 1;
    while(x<=XMAX){
      int n = 1;
      while(n<=NMAX){
       
            
      System.out.printf("%10.0f",Math.pow(x,n));
        n++;
      }
      x++;
    }
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

Any `for` loop can be turned directly into a `while` loop. A `for` loop has this pattern:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    body
}
```

The equivalent `while` structure is:

```
initialization
while (termination) {
    body
    increment
}
```

If it is guaranteed that the body of the `for` loop will be executed at least once (which it is in your specific example, but not in general), you can also turn it into a `do-while` loop:

```
initialization
do {
    body
    increment
} while (termination);
```

Note that if `termination` might be `false` immediately after `initialization`, then the `do-while` structure is **not** equivalent to the `for` loop.

Note also that if the `initialization` expression of a `for` loop includes variable declarations such as the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { ... }
```

then translating it into a `while` or `do-while` loop is not exactly equivalent, because you will then have a local variable `i` that remains in scope past the end of the loop. In a `for` loop, by contrast, any variables declared in the `initialization` go out of scope as soon as the loop exits.

Finally, it's very bad structured programming, but it is possible to use a `do-while` loop combined with an `if` and `break` to exactly replicate the logic of a `for` loop:

```
initialization
do {
    if (!termination) break;
    body
    increment
} while (true);
```

I definitely would recommend against this, but I'm just noting that it is available.

Comment: Thanks Ted, I'm new to programing.